# querySelectorAll find which button is selected JavaScript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am just learning `JavaScript` and I am having an issue with `radio` buttons and `JavaScript`. I have the following code:

```
var cbLoop = document.querySelectorAll('[name="question1"]');
    for(var x in cbLoop){
        if(x.checked){ <-- I assume this is the problem?
            answers[0] = x.value;
        }
    }
```

`question1` refers to 5 `radio` buttons. I want to find which button was selected when the user clicks the `submit` button. I guess, I cant call `.checked` using the `for` loop I have.

Could anybody help?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: ` I am guessing I cant call '.checked'` you're not **calling** it, you're testing it's truthiness - what makes you say you can't do that?

Comment: I cant find the selected radio button.

Comment: `for..in` iterates over properties of an object. Try something like `for (const x of cbLoop)`

Comment: @Jaromanda I was thinking that is the reason I cant find the selected radio button. I am assuming I am performing it incorrectly

Comment: you're using the wrong for loop ;) as pointed out by elclanrs

Comment: @elclanrs Thank you! I had no idea you could use 'of' instead on 'in'. How exactly does that work though?

Comment: by the way, you can avoid the for loop altogether ... `answers[0] = document.querySelector('[name="question1"]:checked').value`

Comment: @ZachLucas - `for ... of` *iterates over iterable objects* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of - whereas for...in *iterates over the enumerable properties of an object* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @Jaromanda I tried that before but I was told that it might not work on older browsers. So I started searching for another method just in case

Comment: use a regular for loop then if you need to support internet exploder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `for ... in` loop you are iterating through the keys not the actual item. 
You can use **Aarry#forEach** like the following:

```js
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var cbLoop = document.querySelectorAll('[name="question1"]');
  var answers =[];
  cbLoop.forEach(function(radio){
    if(radio.checked){ 
        answers[0] = radio.value;
    }
  });
  console.log(answers);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" checked>3</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">4</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">5</input>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
```

**OR:** With `for` loop

```js
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var cbLoop = document.querySelectorAll('[name="question1"]');
  var answers = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < cbLoop.length; i++){
    if(cbLoop[i].checked){ 
        answers[0] = cbLoop[i].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(answers);
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1">1</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" checked>3</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">4</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1">5</input>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Doesn't look like this would work, if anything something like `Array.prototype.forEach.call(cbLoop, function(radio) {`

Comment: it will work in every *modern* browser - but yeah, since OP says `for...of` isn't viable, that means they must support Internet Exploder, so using Array#forEach.call would be one way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard `for` loop:

```js
function check() {
  var cbLoop = document.querySelectorAll('[name="question1"]');
  var answers = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < cbLoop.length; x++) {
    if (cbLoop[x].checked) {
      answers[0] = cbLoop[x].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(answers);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q1" checked>1</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q2">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q3">3</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q4">4</input>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="check();">Check</button>
```

However, there can  never be more than one value selected using the radio buttons, so why are you using an array for the answer? You can use a simple variable:

```js
function check() {
  var cbLoop = document.querySelectorAll('[name="question1"]');
  var answer;
  for (var x = 0; x < cbLoop.length; x++) {
    if (cbLoop[x].checked) {
      answer = cbLoop[x].value;
    }
  }
  console.log(answer);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q1" checked>1</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q2">2</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q3">3</input>
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="Q4">4</input>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="check();">Check</button>
```